# how to calculate integral $\lim_{h \to -\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^{1+2h}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{(1+2h)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus

how to calculate integral,

$\displaystyle\lim_{h \to -\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^{1+2h}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{(1+2h)^3}dx$

Not sure if the limit exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may change your limit by $$\displaystyle\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{{\varepsilon^3}} \int_0^{\varepsilon}{\sin(x^2)}dx$$

At this point, you may use L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sim {1 \over \epsilon^{3}}\int_{0}^{\epsilon}x^{2}\,{\rm d}x 
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large{1 \over 3}}
$$

Comment: you should be a bit more explicit how you come to this solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the range of integration is small, replace Sin[x^2] by its Taylor expansion around x=0 or just remember that Sin[x]/x has a limit of 1 when x->0. Are you able to continue with this ?